# Flask: How to print variable to web page using ajax

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I have the following code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
import datetime
from flask import *
import random

from threading import Thread


app = Flask(__name__)


def Tracking():
    lower = np.array([35, 192, 65])
    upper = np.array([179, 255, 255])

    video = cv2.VideoCapture(1, 0)

    times = []
    total = 0
    is_round = False

    while True:
        success, img = video.read()
        image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
        blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (15, 15), 0)

        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blur, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 14,
                                   param1=34, param2=10, minRadius=4, maxRadius=10)

        circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

        if (len(circles[0, :]) == 7) and not is_round:
            start_time = time.time()
            is_round = True
            curr_count = 0
            round_total = 0

        elif is_round:
            if len(circles[0, :]) == 1:
                end_time = time.time()
                is_round = False
                time_taken = end_time - start_time
                print('time: ', str(
                    datetime.timedelta(seconds=time_taken))[2:7])

                times.append(time_taken)
                average = sum(times) / len(times)
                print('Avg time: ', str(
                    datetime.timedelta(seconds=average))[2:7])

            elif len(circles[0, :]) < 7:
                curr_count = (7 - round_total) - len(circles[0, :])
                total += curr_count
                round_total += curr_count

            for i in circles[0, :]:
                cv2.circle(img, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
                cv2.circle(img, (i[0], i[1]), 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)

        yield total  


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('theme1.html')


gen_total = Tracking()  # initate the function out of the scope of update route


@app.get("/update")
def update():
    global gen_total  

    return str(next(gen_total))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel= "stylesheet"  href= "{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css')}}">

</head>
<body>

    <div class="data">
    <p id="output"></p>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        function update(){
            $.get("/update", function(data){
                $("#output").html(data)
            });
        }
        update()
        var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
            update()
        }, 10000);

    </script>
        
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get the variable 'average' to print to the webpage, i have already added 'total' to the webpage but i am not sure how to add average, this variable will not always have a value as a certain thing has to happen before it is given a value, any help would be appriciated. I am also not sure if this has to be converted to a string to be displayed, ajax is used in the html file to update the page every so often.

Comment: Did you try yielding both values and returning them both from /update?

Comment: i tried it earlier but maybe i did it wrong.... i'm currently trying it again but when i try to return average in /update it says code is unreachable... also the average variable will not always have a value as a certain thing has to happen before it is given a value, will that be a problem? Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what your algorithm is or what you plan to do with the missing data, so that's up to you to decide. Maybe fill it in with `None`.

Comment: I have tried yielding average and i deleted the     return str(next(gen_total))   and replaced it with  return str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=average))[2:7]    however nothing shows up on the webpage.. i'm getting an error NameError: name 'average' is not defined

Comment: Maybe try `yield dict(total=total, average=average)`, then respond with a JSON pair to the front end, `jsonify(next(gen_total))`. I wouldn't worry about date formatting until you have the data heading through the response correctly.

Comment: i've added the yield total, average line along with total, average = next(gen_total) but i am still getting error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'average' referenced before assignment... i made average a global variable aswell and still got the error

Comment: btw i appreciate the help

Comment: That makes sense, `average` is only defined in one branch. So set it to a default value in the loop, or before the loop, whatever the behavior is supposed to be for the algorithm.

Comment: could you provide sample code? it only has to be simple.. i'm not sure if i am doing what you are asking properly because i am still getting the same error. If not, it is ok i will continue to try... i changed average to = 1 just to test if it appears on the webpage but i still get nothing unfortunately.

Comment: Did you put `average = 0` above `while True`: or just inside that block so the `yield` can see it? I don't have cv2 and I generally don't answer unless I can actually run and validate the code. If you simplify the code to show only the critical parts, I can add an answer.

Comment: Good news, i put average above while true and i am now getting an output to the website, however i am not sure how to add my code for average since it is outside the while loop, also both outputs for average and total are in brackets e.g (0,0), how could i make this so they are separate and so i can separately style them in css? also i don't really know how stackoverflow works but if you want to submit a random answer then i will happily accept it (if that benefits you in anyway)

Comment: Thanks, but my main goal is to make the site useful for future visitors, so ideally the answer actually solves the question and the question is self-contained and answerable. Did you use the `dict()` approach? If so, you should have keys and values and you can parse the result as JSON in the front end. `console.log(JSON.parse(data))`. If the instructions so far work I can probably answer it at this point.

Comment: i'm not sure what the dict approach is... if you could help me solve these 2 problems then i will happily accept answer.. i just need it now so the average variable actually does what it is meant to do (instead of outputting 0) and to separate the outputs in the frontend so they are not in brackets

Comment: oh wait sorry i think it is doing it's function... i just need to know how to seperate the variables so i can edit in css

Comment: `data` is an object, the parsed JSON. Use `data.total` to get the total and `data.average` to get the average. See my answer, but I'd also suggest [reading the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) and working through some basic JS tutorials if this is confusing. I can't really tend to this question much longer and I feel like we've resolved the main/original problem more or less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To yield multiple values from your generator, either use a tuple, list, class, dictionary or other data structure. I'd suggest a dict which is simple but has nice naming semantics. `yield dict(total=total, average=average)`.

Since `average` is inside of a conditional branch, it's possible that `yield` is reached without actually initializing this variable, which is illegal. Set a default value that's unconditionally within scope of the `yield` statement so it's guaranteed to have a value.

Finally, return it as JSON to the client rather than text using Flask's `jsonify`.

Here's a simplified example you can adapt:

#### `app.py`

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template


app = Flask(__name__)


def track():
    total = 0
    average = 0

    while True:
        if 1 == 1:
            average += 2

        total += 1
        yield dict(total=total, average=average)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("theme1.html")


@app.get("/update")
def update():
    return jsonify(next(gen_total))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    gen_total = track()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

#### `templates/theme1.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="data">
    <p id="average"></p>
    <p id="total"></p>
  </div>
  <script>
function update() {
  $.get("/update", function (data) {
    $("#average").text("average " + data.average);
    $("#total").text("total " + data.total);
  });
}
update();
var intervalId = setInterval(update, 10000);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey, i've added the jsonify line to my code... that has removed the brackets.. now how do i make it so in html average and total have their own variables so i can seprately edit css? Thanks

Comment: becuase at the minute they are both assigned the output value i think

Comment: Just add another output element with a different id. It's a small modification of the code you already have. See update. I hope you can take it from here.

Comment: average [object HTMLParagraphElement]

total [object HTMLParagraphElement]

Comment: That's the output i'm currently getting

Comment: See the update. I forgot to use `data.` prefix in my first update (this is why I generally don't answer unless I can run the code...)

Comment: average undefined

total undefined

Comment: the output before i copy/pasted your html was 00:00

Comment: Code works fine for me. Did you copy and paste everything exactly as I have here, with no extra files in a clean project? Tested with Ubuntu 22.04, Py 3.10.4, Flask==2.1.3, FF 102.0.1, Chrome 103.0.5060.114. I don't see how "00:00" is possible output.

Comment: it's something to do with function update.. i just swapped it and started working